# Python - Extracts only one when using openAPI

Tags: python, api

I'm extracting movie data from open API.

I want to bring the first director and actor, but everyone is printed out.

This is my code.

```
url = "http://www.kobis.or.kr/kobisopenapi/webservice/rest/movie/searchMovieInfo.json?key='KeyValue'&movieCd=20177478"

res = requests.get(url)
test = res.text

d = json.loads(test)

movieinfo = d['movieInfoResult']['movieInfo']
moviename = movieinfo['movieNm']
print("movie_name = " + moviename)
moviedt = movieinfo['openDt']
print("movie_dt = " + moviedt)
for b in d["movieInfoResult"]["movieInfo"]["directors"]:
    print("director_name = " + b["peopleNm"])
```

When I run this code result is like this.

```
movie_name = avengers
movie_dt = 20180425
director_name = Anthony Russo
director_name = Joe Russo
```

How can I bring only one person like this.

I need just the first person.

```
movie_name = avengers
movie_dt = 20180425
director_name = Anthony Russo
```

Open API site(korean) - https://www.kobis.or.kr/kobisopenapi/homepg/apiservice/searchServiceInfo.do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can break for loop after printing or you can directly access the first value (if you are sure directors array is not empty)

```
url = "http://www.kobis.or.kr/kobisopenapi/webservice/rest/movie/searchMovieInfo.json?key='KeyValue'&movieCd=20177478"

res = requests.get(url)
test = res.text

d = json.loads(test)

movieinfo = d['movieInfoResult']['movieInfo']
moviename = movieinfo['movieNm']
print("movie_name = " + moviename)
moviedt = movieinfo['openDt']
print("movie_dt = " + moviedt)
for b in d["movieInfoResult"]["movieInfo"]["directors"]:
    print("director_name = " + b["peopleNm"])
    break
```

or

```
url = "http://www.kobis.or.kr/kobisopenapi/webservice/rest/movie/searchMovieInfo.json?key='KeyValue'&movieCd=20177478"

res = requests.get(url)
test = res.text

d = json.loads(test)

movieinfo = d['movieInfoResult']['movieInfo']
moviename = movieinfo['movieNm']
print("movie_name = " + moviename)
moviedt = movieinfo['openDt']
print("movie_dt = " + moviedt)
print("director_name = " + d["movieInfoResult"]["movieInfo"]["directors"][0]["peopleNm"])
```